# How to select xml elements within a namespace?

Tags: asp.net, html, xslt, namespaces

I'm trying to understand this xslt.

What does the below xslt command select exactly? what are "following-sibling", "aic" and "pstyle"?

"aic" seems to be a namespace.

What xml input the below xslt work with?

```
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="aic" 
    version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:aic="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInCopy/2.0/" >

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::aic:pstyle"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This XSLT selects nothing.  The root node doesn't have any following siblings.  Where did you get this example?

Comment: that's within a large file. do you want more lines showing the template, etc?

Comment: Yes, preferably at least the template that contains that `value-of` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
following-sibling::aic:pstyle
```

- `following-sibling` is the *axis*, denoting which "direction" to look for nodes, in this case it looks at nodes which are after the current context node in document order but share the same parent as the current node.  If you don't specify an axis the default is `child`, which looks for child nodes of the current context node.
- `aic:pstyle` is a selector that looks for *elements* whose local name is `pstyle` and whose namespace URI is `http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInCopy/2.0/` (the one that is mapped to the prefix `aic` in the stylesheet).

The source XML need not use the same prefix, e.g. the expression would match an element that looks like

```xml
<pstyle xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInCopy/2.0/">
```

or

```
<foo:pstyle xmlns:foo="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInCopy/2.0/">
```

in the original XML.

As JLRishe points out, this particular XPath will not match anything if the current context is the document node `/`, for the expression to be meaningful it would have to be executed in a context where the current node is an element (or comment, processing instruction or text node) at least two levels down i.e. a child of the document element or deeper.

```
<example xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInCopy/2.0/">
  <pstyle id="1"/>
  <foo/>
  <pstyle id="2"/>
  <pstyle id="3"/>
</example>
```

If executed with the `foo` element as the context node, the expression would select pstyle elements 2 and 3, but not 1.

Comment: @TheLight it could be, provided there's an `xmlns:aic="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInCopy/2.0/"` on that element or one of its ancestors higher up (e.g. the top-level document element).  What matters is the namespace URI - the source document uses the prefix that is bound to that URI in the document, the XPath expression uses the prefix that is bound to the same URI in the stylesheet.