# What is cstyle in XSLT?

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, transform

My XSLT is shown below.
aic is a namespace.
What is cstyle?
is it a built-in XSLT element/function?
Or an element within the expected input xml?

```
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="aic" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:aic="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInCopy/2.0/" >

    <xsl:template match="/">
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="aic:cstyle[contains(@name,'bold')]">

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is an element within the expected input XML.  The XPaths in an XSLT's `match` attributes are generally applied to contents from the input XML.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly as in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14729602/592139), `aic:cstyle` is a selector that matches elements whose local name is `cstyle` and whose namespace URI is `http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInCopy/2.0/` (the URI bound to the `aic` prefix in the `xsl:stylesheet` element).  Thus

```
<xsl:template match="aic:cstyle[contains(@name,'bold')]">
```

is a template that will apply to any `{http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInCopy/2.0/}cstyle` element that has a `name` attribute that contains the substring `bold`.  (So, to answer your question directly:  the expression in question will match elements in the input streams for which the stylesheet was written.)

As with any new programming language, I would strongly recommend that you find a decent tutorial and work through that to get comfortable with the syntax and idioms of the language through simple examples before you start trying to decode a large and complex XSLT that you've inherited from elsewhere.